# How do I make a World of Warcraft addon?

Tags: lua, add-on, world-of-warcraft

I want to create a simple addon that will play sound files when the player kills an enemy player (gets a killing blow). I've looked around on Google but haven't found much in terms of documentation or guides.

Can anyone point me to some up-to-date documentation or some places where I can just find better guides?

Comment: I would ask this on gamedev.stackexchange.com

Comment: Addon Studio is pretty cool as well as it gives you a nice IDE to work with:
http://www.wowwiki.com/AddOn_Studio_2010

Comment: Also you have to regularly check Blizzard's changelog about the their API, which is the reason why addons stop working after major patches expansions. So you have to update your code to match the new standards and take advantage of the new addon functions Blizzard implements.

Answer (score 9):

Getting started: http://www.wowpedia.org/Getting_started_with_writing_addons

API: http://www.wowpedia.org/World_of_Warcraft_API

What you want to do is to add a trigger for the combat log event for a killing blow. Shouldn't be to hard. And then play a sound, using the API for that.

Answer (score 4):

Addons for the game are created, most simply, by making a new folder in the `Interface/AddOns` directory in your game folder and populating this with the core files for your addon. These files should include a "Table Of Contents" file which contains information about your addon, and script(s) which are created using the [Lua](http://www.lua.org/) scripting language (with some custom WoW functions and tables and other bits). To properly get started with this, [Wowpedia](http://www.wowpedia.org/Getting_started_with_writing_addons) is generally a pretty good guide, and I also recommend [this tutorial](http://www.dev-hq.net/posts/2--create-world-of-warcraft-addon).

In your specific situation you should just be able to listen for a game event and then do your custom stuff (i.e. playing a sound) in the desired situation. There isn't actually an event for killing blows at the time of writing, however if you register the `COMBAT_LOG_EVENT_UNFILTERED` event and look for the `PARTY_KILL` combat event, calling `playSoundFile` if the sourceName (arg4) matches the player's name (`UnitName("Player")`), [you should be set](http://www.wowinterface.com/forums/showpost.php?p=178955&postcount=3).